# Why is this simple C code snippet causing an infinite loop?

Tags: c, arrays

I read some code snippet (listed below) which may cause an infinite loop:

Why was that? In my view, I just think `a[0]` is ignored in the loop and maybe overflows on `a[10]` because of the array index of `a[10]` is from 0 to 9 in C. I don't understand the essence of the knowledge about loop infinite. What is the explanation?

```
  int main(void) {
      int a[10], i;

      for (i =1; i <= 10; i++) {
         a[i] = 0;
      }

      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `i <= 10` -> `i < 10`. Your array index is overflowing, therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: Your array goes from index 0 to 9, counting starts at 0.

Comment: Is that means the undefined behavior may cause the infinite loop, right ?

Comment: Undefined behavior can cause **anything** .. it's *undefined*

Comment: In this case, `a[10]` *might* be the same memory location as `i`. But that's just guessing. It's undefined, so just fix the problem writing well-defined code.

Answer (score 5):

It is **undefined behaviour**, because you have been trying to store more elements than the array is sized.

So, use `i < 10` in the `for` loop condition instead of `i <= 10`. Also, `i` start with `0` instead of `1` in the `for` loop initialization part.

**The C11 standard says:**

> **J.2 Undefined behavior**
>
> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>   accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>   a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

Answer (score 1):

In your loop your array index is out of range. It is only allowed for an array with the size of `n` to dereference an element from index `0` to index `n-1`. Anything else will lead to undefined behavior.

```
int a[10];
// a[0] <= lowest element
// a[9] <= highest element
```

In your case the memory allocation of the variables looks probably as the following:

```
a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | a[3] | a[4] | a[5] | a[6] | a[7] | a[8] | a[9] | i=a[10]
```

So your loop will execute the following:

```
i=1: a[1]=0;
i=2: a[2]=0;
i=3: a[3]=0;
i=4: a[4]=0;
i=5: a[5]=0;
i=6: a[6]=0;
i=7: a[7]=0;
i=8: a[8]=0;
i=9: a[9]=0;
i=10: a[10] = i = 0;   // <-- undefined behavior, index i will be set to 0

i=0: a[0]=0;
i=1: a[1]=0;
// [...infinite loop...]
```

Comment: initiate the loop with `1=0` and `i<10` can solve the problem, right?

Comment: The important thing is that the array index will not be out of its valid range. So only `i<10` will get it to work. Maybe there is a purpose with starting at `i=1`.

Comment: You should not guess about rationales of an undefined behavior. It's just undefined.

Comment: @willys I agree with you. But the question is why this code snippet causes an infinite loop and not how to get the code working. So I made a guess to provide a satisfying answer.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any issue in your code snippet.

a[10] is an array.

It has a specific location in the memory and can hold 10 integers. The only issue is pointing to the index. Use (0 to 9) or, (1 to 10)

I executed your code, and I got this response:

> Success    time: 0 memory: 9296 signal:0

Ideally, the output should be blank as I executed the code on an online IDE. Please share the output you are getting on the console.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is plain wrong. You should rewrite it or just delete it.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't actually find any compilation or runtime bug in your code. It is absolutely fine. However, you can try like this

```
 int main () {

     int a[ 10 ];
     int i,j;

     /* Initialize elements of array a*/
     for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        a[ i ] = i + 20; /* Set element at location i to i + 20 */
     }

     /* Output each array element's value */
     for (j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
       printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", j, a[j] );
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

Just taking a case, what if the loop starts with `0` and goes up to `9`?

Comment: No, the OP's code is not fine at all.

Comment: It's true there is no compilation  error, and there is a **possibility** there will not be any run-time errors, but OP's code contains UB, which is not fine

Comment: but `i` is not initialized inside the loop and when `a[10] =0` then after `i` is not initialised with `a[10]` value i.e `0`

Comment: Here `a[10] =0` is undefined behaviour, therefore the OP's code is **not fine**.

Comment: `a[10]` is undefined,  but the loop will not iterate till `a[10]`. The loop get terminated after 9 if `i` starts with 0 and iterate till `9`..